# Unix timestamp conversion accuracy for big numbers on Android

Tags: java, android, datetime, unix, unix-timestamp

I'm testing the following value from [the list on this site](http://www.epochconverter.com/timestamp-list):

Regular date: 500, January 1 = Unix Timestamp: -46388678400

However, running the following Java code on Android:

```
GregorianCalendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar(500, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0);
calendar.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
Log.d("timestamp", String.valueOf(calendar.getTimeInMillis() / 1000L));
Log.d("date", String.valueOf(calendar.getTime()));
```

outputs the following results:

```
-46388592000
Sat Jan 01 02:00:00 GMT+02:00 500
```

Trying [the same online converter](http://www.epochconverter.com/) and a few other sites with this Unix time stamp I get from my Android program, I get a whole day difference:

```
Android app:  -46388592000 = Sat Jan 01 00:00:00 GMT
Online sites: -46388592000 = Sat Jan 02 00:00:00 GMT
```

My question is: who's wrong? The online converter, or the Java code on Android?

Does Android/Java loose accuracy on such big numbers? Or is it because of leap seconds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Avoid old date-time classes

You are using troublesome old date-time classes, now legacy. Avoid them. Supplanted by the java.time classes.

## Ancient values not reliable

Do not use date-time values in java.time (nor the old classes) for ancient values such as centuries ago. The date-time types internally count a number of seconds since the epoch of first moment of 1970 UTC. Counting seconds across many past centuries raises issues such as the [Julian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julian_calendar)-Gregorian calendar cut-over. Basically such ancient values are meaningless.

Instead use a `LocalDate` if you want to represent a date from history.

```
LocalDate columbusAttacksAmerica = LocalDate.of( "1492-10-12" );
```

## `Instant`

Though I do not recommending doing so with a historical value, you can parse that large integer as an `Instant`. The [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) class represents a moment on the timeline in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) with a resolution of [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond) (up to nine (9) digits of a decimal fraction).

```
long secondsSinceEpoch = -46_388_678_400L;
Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochSecond ( secondsSinceEpoch );
```

Dump to console.

```
System.out.println ( "secondsSinceEpoch: " + secondsSinceEpoch + " | instant: " + instant );
```

> secondsSinceEpoch: -46388678400 | instant: 0500-01-01T00:00:00Z

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`java.text.SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to java.time.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8) and [**SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [*ThreeTenABP*](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts ***ThreeTen-Backport*** (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer, and for the ThreeTenABP info. As an alternative, after re-reading [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html#setGregorianChange(java.util.Date)), and adding `calendar.setGregorianChange(new Date(Long.MIN_VALUE));` to my code, I get the same (correct?) results as the online site, and your code using `Instant`. This means they are using a pure Gregorian calendar for all dates, which actually is not historically correct (it was instituted in 1582). What approach do you think is the correct one in this case?